# What the minimum of infinite tetration divided by $\sqrt{x}$?

Tags: optimization, tetration, power-towers

For some values of $x$ the limit of infinite tetration converges. For example when $x=\sqrt{2}$ this is fixed point

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{2} \uparrow \uparrow n = \sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot}}}}} = \sqrt{2}$$

This [limit converges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Extension_to_infinite_heights) for all $e^{-e} \le x \le e^{1/e}$. What is the minimum of this function?

$$f(x) = \frac{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{x} \uparrow \uparrow n}{\sqrt{x}} $$

Numerically the answer looks to have a single minima at $f(x\approx 0.579690102929) = 0.687413037245$, is there an exact solution?

[image]

Comment: I think you shouldn't have $\sqrt 2$ in your definition of $f$. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @Watson you're correct, thanks, and fixed!

Comment: The key, why $x=\sqrt{2}$ works is not because it is a root, but an exponential of the form $x=b^{1\over b}$ at $b=2$. Thus a better generalization is for instance $ ^3 \sqrt{3}$ etc. After that try to find the number $b$ where $x=2 = b^{1 \over b}$ and look what happens when you evaluate x^b,x^x^b,x^x^x^b,... resp 2^b,2^2^b, 2^2^2^b,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\W{\operatorname W}$
The asker’s plot and numerical minimum do not match, but the following does match their plot:

$$\min\left(\frac{x^{x^{\unicode{x22F0} }}}{\sqrt x}\right)=0.902858\dots,x=0.579687\dots$$

[Rewriting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2681174/tetration-as-an-iterative-solution-for-the-transcendental-equation-sqrtxx?rq=1) the infinite tetration with [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) and using $x=e^{-we^w}$:

$$-\frac d{dx}\frac{\W(-\ln(x))}{\sqrt x\ln(x)}=\frac{\W(-\ln(x))(\ln(x)+\W(-\ln(x))(\ln(x)+2))}{2(\W(-\ln(x))+1)x^\frac32\ln^2(x)}=0\implies e^w(w+1)=2$$

Therefore the minimum is at:

$$\left(e^{\frac2{\W(2e)}-2},\frac{\W\left(2-\frac2{\W(2e)}\right)\W(2e)}{2 e^{\frac1{\W(2e)}-1}(\W(2e)-1)}\right)$$

[shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=min%5B-ProductLog%28-log%28x%29%29%2F%28%E2%88%9Ax+log%28x%29%29%5D):
[image]